# When should I use the inexact number prefix (#i)?

Tags: racket

If I understand correctly, numbers in Racket are inexact by default. So under what conditions should I explicitly use the inexact number prefix (`#i`)? What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers in Racket are not inexact by default. E.g., rationals and integers (without `.0`) are exact.

So for me, I'd use `#i` when I want to write an inexact number that is close to a rational number. Something like `#i22/7`.